# Gulp-pug no funciona

Tags: jade, gulp, pug

Estoy probando **gulp** y en particular el plugin **gulp-pug** para compilar Pug. No parece tener mucha ciencia el hacerlo funcionar pero sin embargo no hay forma.

No estoy realizando ningún proyecto, simplemente estoy probando el 'task runner' **Gulp** y en particular el plugin **Gulp-pug** (que es lo que no me funciona)

Mi gulpfile es el siguiente:

```
'use strict'

var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require("browser-sync").create();
var pug = require('gulp-pug')
var sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  sass('./scss/**/*.scss')
    .on('error', sass.logError)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'))
});

gulp.task('pug', function () {
  gulp.src('./pug/*.pug')
    .pipe(pug())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
});

gulp.task('serve', function() {
  browserSync.init({
    server: "./"
  });
  gulp.watch("./scss/**/*.scss", ['sass']);
  gulp.watch("./pug/**/*.pug", ['pug']);
  gulp.watch(["./*.html", "./css/*.css"]).on('change', browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch("./js/*.js").on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('default', ['serve']);
```

Por supuesto tengo instalado **Pug** y funciona perfectamente. Lo e utilizado con **grunt** y desde consola sin problema.

No tira ningun error, solo pone

```
Starting 'pug'...
Finished 'pug' after 12 ms
```

Pero ni rastros del **.html**

Entiendo que no esta conectando con **Pug** y por lo tanto no hace nada. pero no se como solucionarlo.

Agrego un poco mas de informacion.

El archivo que debria compilarse (o traspilar) es el siguiente:

```
doctype html
html(lang="es")
  head
    meta(charset="utf-8")
    title Prueba
  body
    .wrapper
      header.hidden
        h1 HOLA MUNDO
```

Que como se ve no tiene nada extraño.

y la estructura de archivos.

```
/:.
|   gulpfile.js
|   package.json
|   
+---css
|       style.css
|       
+---node_modules
|   +--- etc...
|       
\---pug
    |   index.pug
```

Omito todo el contenido de la carpeta 'node modules' porque es demasiado extenso y no aporta demasiado que este.

Saludos

Comment: ¿Seguro que es el directorio correcto? ¿Estás usando Node.js como backend?

Comment: Gracias por responder Gustavo. Node es necesario para que funcione gulp y pug. No veo que el directorio este mal.

Comment: No te comenté lo de Node.js por eso porque es obvio si no no correría Gulp. Te lo comenté porque si usas Node.js como backend, entonces la compilación puede ser automática en el servidor.

Comment: Si, disculpa, te respondí cualquier cosa. Ahí agrego mas información en el post. Estoy haciendo pruebas en local.

Comment: Hace mucho no trabajo con Gulp (trabajo con Webpack y FuseBox) pero, según recuerdo allí no estás compilando **hasta que se produzcan cambios** en los templates. En todo caso, si quisiera que se ejecute la compilación al empezar, deberías empezar con `gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'pug', 'serve']);`.

Comment: Cuando llamas a la tarea serve esta llama a sass y a pug y se queda observando hasta que se produzca un cambio. Con sass funciona correctamente. De todas formas estuve probando lanzar la tarea pug directamente con 'gulp pug', que ejecuta la tarea pero el .html no aparece...

Comment: Prueba cambiando el alias, en lugar de `**/*.pug` pon `*.pug`.

Comment: Me temo que no pasa nada. Simplifique todo dejando solo la tarea de gulp-pug y nada.

Comment: No le veo el sentido realmente. Pásale `{ debug: true }` a pug para que depure mientras realiza la tarea. La información que te bote dará pistas sobre el problema.

Comment: Bueno... no paso nada pero se me ocurrió probar cambiar la ubicación del proyecto. 
El problema estaba en el nombre de la carpeta donde se encontraba la carpeta del proyecto. Mas precisamente por estar entre corchetes.

[proyecto] > prueba-gulp

Me imagino que es un problema con gulp-pug y con gulp-sass porque con otros plugins no tube problemas (gulp-ruby-sass, browser-sync)

Muchas gracias Gustavo.

Comment: Si ya encontraste la forma de solucionarlo publica tu respuesta y autoaceptala para que los demás sepan como solucionarlo, si les ocurre.

Answer (score 0):

Que tal buenas tardes.

No conozco **Pug** pero por lo que veo es un template system y como tal necesita datos (contexto) para poder ser usado.

Según su documentación el método de compilación sólo te devolverá una función, que podrá ser llamada más adelante con los datos de tu aplicación:

```
// Compile the source code
const compiledFunction = pug.compileFile('template.pug');

// Render a set of data
console.log(compiledFunction({
  name: 'Timothy'
}));
```

¿Tendrás tu código en algún repositorio en Github para poderle dar un vistazo?

Saludos cordiales.

Comment: Gracias por contestar Alex. Con pug no tengo ningún problema, lo que no me funcione es **Gulp**, o mas bien el plugin que trabaja con pug, **Gulp-pug**. Ahí agrego algo mas de información. No hay mucho mas que lo que pongo en el post.

Comment: Interesante, sólo para estar seguro esto es Pug ¿verdad? https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html

Comment: Si, antes se llamaba Jade

Answer (score 0):

Debo suponer que los módulos están bien instalados.

Partiendo tengo una observación: Aunque hice una prueba con proyecto con una distribución similar no me dio error, a pesar de que no incluí el ";" al finalizar la instrucción en el require('gulp-pug') como lo tienes.

Ahora, no veo que el código este mal, pero te comparto 2 versiones mis tareas en gulp que he manejado y que me han funcionado tanto para .jade como para .pug.

Este es para el .jade

```
 var gulp = require('gulp');
 var jade = require('gulp-jade');

 gulp.task('views', function() {
    var YOUR_LOCALS = {};
    // -------------------------------------  
    gulp
       .src('./src/jade/*.jade')
       .pipe(jade({
             locals: YOUR_LOCALS,
             pretty: true
       }))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
 });
```

Este para el .pug

```
 var gulp = require('gulp');
 var pug = require('gulp-pug');

 gulp.task('views', function (){ 
    // ------------------------------------- 
    gulp.src('./pug/*.pug', { base: './pug/' })
        .pipe(pug({ 
            locals: {}, 
            pretty: true 
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gulp.task('pug', function () {
  gulp.src('./pug/*.pug')
    .pipe(pug())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
});
```

prueba quitando el `'/'`

te debe quedar  asi en la raiz del proyecto

```
gulp.task('pug', function () {
  gulp.src('./pug/*.pug')
    .pipe(pug())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.'))
});
```